# Text Baseline with Android Canvas (hanging, ideographic)

Tags: android, android-canvas, baseline

I'm looking for a way to implement some base line features using androids canvas. 
Using functions like ascent and descent of the Paint object I've managed to implement most of the base lines but I don't know how the **'hanging'** and **'ideographic'** base lines could be implemented.

Does anybody know a way to calculate the offset required to draw text for these base lines?

[image: Base Lines]
<sub>(source: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_textbaseline.gif))</sub>